# Unit testing frameworks for Intersystems Caché

Tags: unit-testing, intersystems-cache

Are there any unit testing frameworks for Intersystems Caché?  If so, please list some.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, it is not on topic for the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caché has a built-in one - see their documentation of the [%UnitTest package](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25UnitTest).  Also, they have a fairly decent [tutorial](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TUNT) in their documentation that you can reference.  Granted, %UnitTest is a bit quirky and not as fully featured as the more well-known xUnit test frameworks, but it's great if you have nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I was in the same situation you are in and I didn't think any existing unit test frameworks were very good, so I ported an early version of JUnit as described in [JUnit A Cook's Tour](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm).

Back in the early versions of the original *Unit (I forget the exact name) the author wouldn't distribute source code, but would guide people through writing their own version, so they would feel confident to modify it to suit their needs.  I spent at most 1/2 a day on it before I wrote my first unit test in it.  I would recommend doing the same.

I'd give you the source code but I don't own it and I don't want to have that conversation with the owner of my company.

Comment: Sounds good.  I appreciate it.  I will use cache in another month or so.